# Jquery: railscast 114, alert not showing, is this because it's coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm following a railscast tutorial #114 for endless scrolling but I don't use coffeescript. THe javascript provided does not work when calling the alert. What is the problem here? Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll ->
      if $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
        alert "near bottom"
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fskx4jyr/

If this is a coffeescript problem, how would this code be used to working in just jquery?

```
jQuery ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
        $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...")
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()
```

Comment: A little late but watch episode 267 of railscast to see why that javascript won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the error in your code try running this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50))
      {
         alert("near bottom");
      }
     });

 });
```

You had syntax mistakes in your jquery function. Hope this helps :)

You can check the same [here](http://jsfiddle.net/19nnt20g/)